# RESTful move action

Tags: web-services, http, rest, web-applications

I want to create a simple web app for keeping track of whom to bring cake for the friday morning meeting.

So I imagine having two resources: *person* and *date* where each date is assigned one person.

But when I for instance would like to move Johns assignment for week 42 to week 38 and shift the assignments for weeks 39-42, I get puzzled because rest does not have a MOVE primitive.

For now, my plan is

```
POST http://rundstykkeliste.dk/week/38?person=John&move_from=42
```

is this RESTful?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should work with regular posts, and your API user either modifies the person itself (the date that person should bring cake), or the date object (the person assigned for that date). But I don't see why you should have those two objects have such a weird relationship, or allow the API user to change them both.

Comment: The reason that I want to make the move operation atomic is such that I am sure that the controller maintains that each date is only assigned one person